# HTTP - PUT method returns status 200 but no data being put into the database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, next.js, put

I am new and I'm lost as to why my PUT request did not inserting the data into the database.

```
    const orderId = JSON.stringify(1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000));

    await fetch(`http://0.0.0.0:9010/fdb/pos/collection/order/${orderId}`, {
        "method": "PUT",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify({
            merchantId,
            "_id": orderId,
            "lineItems": cartItems,
            "paymentIntent": paymentIntent.id,
            "status": "stripePendingPayment",
            "rejectedReason": "",
            "totalPrice": String(basketTotalPrice * 100),
            "updatedTs": new Date(),
            "createdTs": new Date()
        })
    }).then(r => console.log(r.status));
```

Log returned status 200 but no data. It works with POST method but not PUT. Does anyone have any idea as to why that is?

Any input is welcome with thanks in advance.

Comment: If you got a 200 OK, you expected something to happen but didn't then this is a server-side issue.

Answer (score 0):

PUT is for updating the data, maybe this method just says you updated succesfully the content.

Comment: Yes, it obviously accepted the connection but the data is missing from the server.

Comment: Check the backend end point for this method or share with us for a better understanding. This method shall return nothing and just update your data but with no code i'm not sure.